# Another Coercion Failed Workflow Error

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow that looks up "informants" to send emails to at different steps based on a key (workflow variable) built from form fields.  I have a separate list with the items with the key and a number of person fields.  When the lookup returns a name, all is well.  However, if the lookup does not return a name because the other lists' item has the field blank, the workflow bombs.

Is there a way around this? I test for empty or is not empty before I try and use the field, but the workflow appears to be dead by then.